# embedding Facebook Video with oembed

Tags: 7, files, social-network, nodes

What is the proper way to embed a (public) facebook video with the [oembed field](https://www.drupal.org/project/oembed) module?

I tried including a video with a link like `https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=55555555555` but when I tested the link I got an error message (log didn't reveal details).

> `https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=55555555555` is not valid oEmbed URL. Please check the error log for messages.

It also doesn't show up in the content type field.

The default schemes didn't do the trick:

```
http://www.facebook.com/video/video.php*
https://www.facebook.com/photo.php*
https://www.facebook.com/video/video.php*
```

So I've added this `https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=*` in the media - oembed settings for facebook.

still, it didnt work.

Any ideas on what URL I have to provide for this to work?

**EDIT:**

I've posted an answer that worked for me.

Ideally, it should work without an embed.ly API key.

Answer (score 1):

turned out i needed an API key for embedly service from http://embed.ly/. here is a good guide on oembed http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode54

strange. some images showed up even without an API key.

Answer (score 0):

This has changed since this question was asked and answered. FB now fully supports integration with `oEmbed` and there is an easier way to include both videos and posts in a website.

You can check the documentation for doing so in their official page [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/oembed-endpoints).